# Alternate Solution to Window.name for cross domain string storage

Tags: javascript, dom

I have been using window.name hack as a way to store some non-secure local data in between domains on the same widow using the window.name property.

This feature has been blocked in the latest version of Chrome, I can't think of any other way to achieve the same in Chrome.

This has to be done on the client side since I don't have access to the servers. Does anyone know of any alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `window.postMessage` to pass strings back and forth.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage

Comment: I want to avoid having to use an iframe if possible